# close excel application with VBa

Tags: vba, userform

I have written a small programm that consists of several userforms that are being called by each other. That means that if I press a button on Userform A, this Userform A closes and Userform B appears, and so on.

They all read and write Data from a Excel file.

My goal is it, since it should be a "independent" program, that the customer/user of that UserformSeries does not touch this Excel file and everything is done via the Userforms.

That`s why I have already programmed that when opening the Excel file, the first "home" userform appears and the Excel file is minimized.

I would like to save and close the workbook.
And then I would like to close the excel application

somehow `Application.Quit` does not work properly (Excel application does not close)

Do you have an idea how to close the appilcation

Thanks in advance
Yours Jonas

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any line of code displayed by you. I imagined a small example for you. See Step 1 & Step 2 and try to do it with your VBA code and let me know..

```
Private Sub cmdLeaveExcel_Click()
  'UserForm_initialize
  Unload ufMyActiveUserForm 
  Application.Quit 'quit Excel --> Step 1
  ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True 'Close the active Excel workbook. --> Step 2
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

To each of the UserForms, add a Close button that in addition to closing the form also saves and closes the workbook.